# How to recommend a native app when viewing web app in devices?

Tags: ios, web-applications, google-play, app-store, nativeapplication

Have you ever used gmail in your Android or iOS using your browser. While browsing it you get a small popup at the top saying that to view/install the native gmail app available at Google Play or AppStore. How do you do that? Is that feature done using html, css, and JS. Or is it built-in to native app?

By the way, this doesn't happen only for gmail but pretty much all the professional apps with both web apps and native apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, you're thinking of [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html), which are a website configuration detail to display a banner for the user to view your iOS app in the App Store:

[image]

Comment: For Android, I would need to use this. https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner

Comment: Thanks @garrettmurray.